# Javascript: Where do i add the redirection?

Tags: javascript

I just need my form to redirect the user to another page after validation using javascript.

Here is my code:

```
function checkEnq() {
     var x = document.forms["enq"]["email"].value;
     var y = document.forms["enq"]["dB"].value;
     var z = document.forms["enq"]["textF"].value;
     if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || z == null || z == "") { 
         alert("Please make sure all fields are entered.");
     }
}
```

How do i add the `location.href` or `window.open` once the js has checked that all fields (email, dB,& textF) are filled?

i can add `target="_blank" action="./result.html"` to the `<form>` field and it will still redirect to the result page even if the form is not filled up completely.

Comment: can't you add redirection in else block ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a "else" block

```
function checkEnq() {
     var x = null;
     var y = null;
     var z = null;
     try {
          x = document.forms["enq"]["email"].value;
          y = document.forms["enq"]["dB"].value;
          z = document.forms["enq"]["textF"].value;
     } catch(e) {
         alert('code error'); 
     };

     if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || z == null || z == "") { 
         alert("Please make sure all fields are entered.");
     } else {
         document.location.href="/redirect.page"
     }
}
```

Comment: i did that and it doesnt redirect me to my page :( @pagetronic

Comment: Verify that email, dB and textF exist with attribute name as identity

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this `window.open("./page.html")`  instead of `document.location.href`